# What should I fix to create random calculation in this code?

Tags: c

I wanted to fix my code to create random operation here, what should I fix here?

```c
    #include <stdio.h>

    int main()
    {
        int x,y,z,a;
        char o;
        while(1)
        {
            printf("give your three numbers: ");
            scanf("%d %d %d",&x,&y,&z);
            printf("(%d*%d-%d) what is the correct among following answers? \n 1. %d\n 2. %d\n 3. %d\n ", 
            x,y,z,x*y-z,x*y*z,x-y*z);
            printf("what is answer? \n: ");
            scanf("%d",&a);
            if(a == 1)
            {
                printf("you are right!\n");
            }
            else
            {
                printf("you are false!\n\n");
            }

            getchar();
            printf("Would you like to exit programm? (y/n) : ");
            scanf("%c",&o);
            if (o=='Y' || o=='y')
            {
                break;
            }
            else if(o=='N' || o=='n')
            {
                continue;
            }
            else
            {
                printf("Wrong input!!!!");
            }
            return 0;
        }
    }
```

What I mean is I want to try change operation such as * + - randomly when I run code, and also along with this question, the answer should be changed...
thank you!

Comment: Please indent your code. This is **very** important as it makes your code more readable so **you** (and we) can find bugs and logic errors more easily.

Comment: So, you want a random operator generator which also generates a few possible answers (including the correct answer) for the user to select. Is that it?

Comment: Use [`srand`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/numeric/random/srand) and [`rand`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/numeric/random/rand).

Comment: @CRM yes it is!

Comment: Don't use `rand`, use `random`.  It's more portable and produces better results.  On some systems they're the same, but not on all.  The man page for `rand` says to use `random` instead.

Comment: @RobertSsupportsMonicaCellio See my comment.  People should use `random`, not `rand`.

Comment: `rand()` is defined by the Standard; `random()` is not. Apparently one library implementation uses a bad generator and its documentation suggests using a non-Standard generator rather than fixing (and possibly break programs that rely on poor generator) its own. @TomKarzes

Comment: @pmg Historically `rand` came first, and was very poor, particularly in the low-order bits.  This dates back to the original Unix implementations, and the first C libraries. 
 `random` replaced it on Unix systems.  Many later implementations later changed `rand` to be an alias for `random`.  I guess some non-Unix systems only support `rand`, unfortunately.  But if you're running on a Unix system and care about the quality of your random numbers, `random` is preferred.  It's unfortunately that the C standard never added `rand` instead of `random`.

Comment: @TomKarzes: on un\*x another option for good random numbers is reading `/dev/urandom` ---- for the OP intents, `rand()`, however bad, *is fine* :)

Answer (score 1):

Your question is mainly focused on shuffling the answers. By studying from couple of sites I have found an solution for this. This is little bit difficult but studying the code few times you can get it

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

void swap(int *a, int *b) {
    int temp = *a;
    *a = *b;
    *b = temp;
}

void randomize(int arr[], int n) {
    srand(time(NULL));
    int i;
    for(i = n-1; i > 0; i--) {
        int j = rand() % (i+1);
        swap(&arr[i], &arr[j]);
    }
}

int main() {
    int x,y,z,a;
    int i;
    int a1, a2, a3;
    int arr[] = {1, 2, 3};
    int n = sizeof(arr)/ sizeof(arr[0]);

    printf("give your three numbers: ");
    scanf("%d %d %d",&x,&y,&z);

    a1 = x*y-z;
    a2 = x*y*z;
    a3 = x-y*z;

    printf("Before shuffle = %d %d %d\n\n", a1, a2, a3);

    char answers[] = {a1, a2, a3};

    printf("(%d*%d-%d)what is the correct among following answers?\n", x, y, z);

    randomize (arr, n);
    for(i=0; i<n; i++) {
        int index = arr[i];
        printf("%2d - %d\n", i+1, answers[index]);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

**This is the outputs**

**First time run**

```
give your three numbers: 2
2
2
Before shuffle = 2 8 -2

(2*2-2)what is the correct among following answers?
 1 - 8
 2 - 2
 3 - -2
```

**Second time run**

```
give your three numbers: 2
2
2
Before shuffle = 2 8 -2

(2*2-2)what is the correct among following answers?
 1 - -2
 2 - 8
 3 - 2
```

You can try this multiple times. Every time answers will be shuffle. This is the [Source](https://bits.mdminhazulhaque.io/c/shuffle-items-of-array-in-c.html) I have referred.

Answer (score 0):

Just provide one of examples here. There are many kinds way to implement. In the random operation generation part. I would like to write a random number generator function, which purpose is to generate the given range of random number.

```cpp
int gen_random(int min, int max)
{
    srand( time(NULL) );
    return rand() % (max - min + 1) + min;
}
```

In order to represent four operator (+, -, *, /), The number (let's call the operation number) 1 to 4 is used for represent four operator respectively. The calculation function map the operation number to operation and get the result.

```cpp
int calculation(int number1, int number2, int op)
{
    switch(op)
    {
        case 1:
            return number1 + number2;
        case 2:
            return number1 - number2;
        case 3:
            return number1 * number2;
        case 4:
            return number1 / number2;
    }
}
```

You can use the gen_random and the calculation function above to change operation randomly. The usage of the gen_random and the calculation function is something like:

```cpp
    int op = gen_random(1, 4);        //  Generate operation randomly
    printf("%d\n", op);
    printf("%d\n", calculation(x, y, op));        //  Pass x, y, and operation number into calculation function to get answer
```